# Mongoose schema validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

in schema i have

```
email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Email is required"],
        unique: true
    }
for validation with "unique" i am create
schema.path('email').validate(function(v){
    mongoose.models['User'].findOne({email: this.email}, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
            if(user){
                this.invalidate("email", "Email exists!");
            }
        }
    });
}, null);
```

but i have an error: 
this.invalidate is not a function. Who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [asynchronous validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate):

```
schema.path('email').validate(function(email, callback) {
  mongoose.models['User'].findOne({ email : mail }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(false, 'Unable to check for e-mail uniqueness due to database error');
    } else if (user) {
      return callback(false, 'E-mail should be unique');
    } else {
      return callback(true);
    }
  });
});
```